# How to sort pandas columns based on letter _and_ number?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which lists out wells in a 96- or 384-well plate, and I would like them sorted. The wells are labelled as such:

```
A1, A2, A3, ..., A10, A11, A12, B1, B2, B3,...
```

In my pandas DataFrame, sorting by the `well` column gives me:

```
A1, A10, A11, A12, A2, A3, ...
```

However, the sorted order above is what I desire.

Apart from splitting the column into a letter and a number column, and then sorting by two columns, is there an alternative that might be smarter or more concise?

Comment: Possibly, though this does involve sorting with a pandas DataFrame rather than a list. The suggestion is helpful, though, and I suspect there may be a function I can add to `pyjanitor` that gets `natsort` working with dataframes.

Comment: as a side tip, if you ever need a list of wells IDs that's sorted out-of-the-box, you can simply use `[letter+str(num) for letter in 'ABCDEFGH' for num in range(1, 13)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
l = ['A1', 'A10', 'A3', 'A2', 'A11', 'A12', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
sorted(l,key = lambda x: (x[0],int(x[1:])))
```

Or [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
import natsort as ns
ns.natsorted(l)

['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
```

---

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
```

Comment: You can add natsort :-) more common ~

Comment: Thanks all. I'm going to accept natsort as the answer for now, as it's the most convenient of the provided ones.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that only uses pandas. Also handle the case when the prefix text is variable in length: `Sales1`, `Region1`, `Product1`, etc.

```
# Extract the columns into a separate series and sort the series
s = df.columns.to_series()
s.index = s.str.extract('(\D+)(?P<num>\d+)').assign(num=lambda x: x['num'].astype('int'))
s.sort_index(inplace=True)

# Access the columns in sorted order. Note that you are not changing
# the dataframe at all
df[s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- For a standard Python `list`, you can do it like this:

  ```
  >>> my_list = ['R10', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R1']
  >>> my_list.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0], int(x[1:])))
  >>> my_list 
  ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10']
  ```
- For a `pandas` DataFrame, you can try this:

  ```
  >>> df = pd.DataFrame({
  ...      "regions": ['R10', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R1'],
  ...      "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
  ... })
  ... 

  >>> df.sort_values(
  ...     by='regions',
  ...     inplace=True,
  ...     key=lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)').squeeze().astype(int)
  ... )
  ... 
  >>> df
  regions  value
  9    R1  100
  1    R2  20
  2    R3  30
  3    R4  40
  4    R5  50
  5    R6  60
  6    R7  70
  7    R8  80
  8    R9  90
  0    R10 10
  ```
- Also you can check this [link](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) as well.